# How can detected image using mobilenetv2-yolov3 cropped?

Tags: python

I am running Mobilenetv2-Yolov3 model for single object detection in the image and it detects my target object successfully and save only detected part rather than full image again, How is it possible, and can any help me with this problem? the github repo I used was: https://github.com/fsx950223/mobilenetv2-yolov3

Comment: What you have tired to solve your problem, what did you found while doing research about your issue? Please provide your idea also if you have any These things will help us to know about your issue and solve it.

Comment: Training the model is fine and it was detecting one object. Then from main.py python script mode= Crop is called which can crop already annotated data which works well, while mode= image can take an image and draw bounding box with IoU score but i need the image detected to be cropped . Then the detected image(cropped ) to be displayed in GUI

Comment: Add this comment data into question! That could help you, some research results also! And try asking single question in one question,  I think you are asking multiple questions here!